# Sorting data lines from serial port

Tags: java

I have a program that sends a string of data over the serial port.

I would like to sort the data string into different arrays so that I can display them or calculate an average of the number.

The numbers are separated by commas. The first number is always 0, and is not used, the same for the number after *.
The next number is the one that defines what the next number after comma is.

```
    #0,    1,5.430,    4,-55.3,    5,6.60,    6,151.0,    51,5.500*16
    #0,    1,5.440,    51,5.400*22
    #0,    1,5.480,    4,-55.0,    5,6.50,    6,151.0*37
    #0,    1,5.490,    4,-53.7,    5,6.70,    51,5.500*02
```

Since I'm unable to insert pictures I have added a [TAB] to show the different groups different groups, and added a [TAB]

The programs don't always send the same length of line.

Array "1"  contains number "5.430"

Array "4" contains number "-55.3"

Array "5" contains number "6.60"

And so on.

Comment: Do you mean to have an array per index (1, 4, 5, 6 and 51)? Are the columns on each line always separated by comma and tab?

Comment: The string is not separated with tab. I need to place the numbers after 1,4,5,6 and 51 into different arrays to be able to display them in the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already got the whole communication over a serial port thing worked out, and that the second line IS a valid data set, I would wrap your serial stream with a `Scanner`, and structure it as such:

```
String[] arrayAndValue;
int arrayToken;
double arrayValue;
Scanner serScanner = new Scanner(myInputStream);
serScanner.useDelimiter("[\\p{JavaWhiteSpace}+||\*dd]");   
While(serScanner.hasNext()) {
    scannedItem = serScanner.nextString;
    arrayAndValue=scannedItem.split(",");
    arrayToken =Integer.parseInt(arrayAndValue[0]);
    arrayValue =Double.parseDouble(arrayAndValue[1]; 
    //insert a switch statement here, 
    //based on the different values arrayToken could have
}
```

What I did there was to use the `Scanner` class to parse `myInputStream` into pairs of array tags and values, `arrayToken` and `arrayValue` respectively as a `String`, and then split that String using the `,` OR a pattern of a `*` followed by two digits.

That will result in a String array of length 3, with the first containing the `arrayToken`, the second the `arrayValue`, and the third being an empty string (created because of the trailing comma).

Then you use the `Integer.parseInt` and `Double.parseDouble` calls to translate them, and then add them to the appropriate array in your `switch` statement later.
I would recommend you input the items into `ArrayLists` instead of `Arrays` if you do not know the exact number of each type you will be receiving though.

Comment: I might need to fix the regEx used as the delimiter.  Please suggest an edit if I'm a bit rusty.

Comment: Seems like a good solution. I think I'd go with a HashMap<Integer, List<Double>> for the data. ArrayList is a good choice.

Comment: @flesk yeah.  a Hashmap is definitely the better choice.  I typically create my own record object and throw it into the arrayList, but here hashmap is DEFINITELY the right choice.